# Can not use Azure Speech golang SDK on Macos

Tags: azure, macos, go, azure-speech

When I followed the official [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/quickstarts/setup-platform?pivots=programming-language-go&tabs=windows%2Cubuntu%2Cdotnetcli%2Cdotnet%2Cjre%2Cmaven%2Cbrowser%2Cmac%2Cpypi#install-the-speech-sdk) to use Azure Speech [SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-go) golang , I am getting  `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` error. Changed the architecture value etc but it didn't work.

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.20.5/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64/link: running cc failed: exit status 1
 ld: warning: -no_pie is deprecated when targeting new OS versions
 ld: warning: ignoring file <speech-sdk-path>/lib/x86/libMicrosoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.core.so, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 )
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
   "_add_source_lang_config_to_auto_detect_source_lang_config", referenced from:
       __cgo_c0b4197be0b1_Cfunc_add_source_lang_config_to_auto_detect_source_lang_config in 000011.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these [instructions](https://github.com/microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-go/issues/72#issuecomment-1339115103) in an issue under the cognitive-services-speech-sdk-go repo, I finally figured out that Azure guidelines are not updated correctly for MacOS.

Install Speech SDK to your Mac

```
export SPEECHSDK_ROOT="/your/path"
mkdir -p "$SPEECHSDK_ROOT"
wget -O MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.xcframework.zip https://aka.ms/csspeech/macosbinary
unzip MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.xcframework.zip -d "$SPEECHSDK_ROOT"
```

Setup compiler and linker flags for Go

```
export CGO_CFLAGS="-I$SPEECHSDK_ROOT/MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.xcframework/macos-arm64_x86_64/MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.framework/Headers"
export CGO_LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$SPEECHSDK_ROOT/MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.xcframework/macos-arm64_x86_64 -F$SPEECHSDK_ROOT/MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech.xcframework/macos-arm64_x86_64 -framework MicrosoftCognitiveServicesSpeech"
```

After this you should be able to use Azure Speech SDK golang in your project.

[Source](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/quickstart/cpp/macos/from-microphone/README.md?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003781&ref=huuhka.net)